# Adjust values in a list by normalizing_zybook

Tags: python, normalization

1.7 LAB: Adjust values in a list by normalising

When analysing data sets, such as data for human heights or for human weights, a common step is to adjust the data. This can be done by normalising to values between 0 and 1, or throwing away outliers.

Write a program that first gets a list of integers from input. The input begins with an integer indicating the number of integers that follow. Then, adjust each integer in the list by subtracting the smallest value from all the integers.

Ex: If the input is:

```
5
30
50
10
70
65
```

the output is:

```
20
40
0
60
55
```

The 5 indicates that there are five integers in the list, namely 30, 50, 10, 70, and 65. The smallest value in the list is 10, so the program subtracts 10 from all integers in the list.

Anyone can solve this question in python?

This is my code.

```
arr1 = []

input = int()

for i in range(0,input):
    e = int(intput())
    
arr1.append(e)

k = min(arr1)

for i in range(0,val):
    arr1[i] = arr1[i] - k
    
for i in range(0,val):
    print(arr1[i])
```

Here is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    arr1.append(e)
NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension:

```
input = [5,30,50,10,70,65]
input = input[1:]
output = [i - min(input) for i in input]
```

---

```
print(output)
[20, 40, 0, 60, 55]
```

Comment: As with the OP, you have made the mistake of using the name of an existing (useful) function as a variable name. You should aim to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I solved it

```
list = []

values = int(input())

for n in range(values):
    number = float(input())
    list.append(number)

largest = max(list)

for number in list:
    number = number / largest
    print(f'{number:.2f}')
```

Comment: You shoul always try to avoid using the names of built-in function or types like `list` as variable names.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_minimum_int(nums):
    low = min(nums)
    return low

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = int(input())
    nums = []
    while num != -1:
        nums.append(num)
        num = int(input())
    l = get_minimum_int(nums)
    for n in nums:
        print(n - l)
```

Answer (score 0):

idk if your question ever got answered but I also had the same type of task.
Mine was:
"For this program, adjust the values by dividing all values by the largest value. The input begins with an integer indicating the number of floating-point values that follow.

Output each floating-point value with two digits after the decimal point, which can be achieved as follows:
print('{:.2f}'.format(your_value))

Ex: If the input is:

```
5
30.0
50.0
10.0
100.0
65.0
```

the output is:

```
0.30
0.50
0.10
1.00
0.65
```

The 5 indicates that there are five floating-point values in the list, namely 30.0, 50.0, 10.0, 100.0, and 65.0. 100.0 is the largest value in the list, so each value is divided by 100.0."

So this is how I solved mine:

```
x = int(input())
dislist = []


i = 1
while i <= x:
    y = float(input())
    dislist.append(y)
    i += 1

q = max(dislist)


for item in dislist:
    item = item / q
    print('{:.2f}'.format(item))
```

Tell me what you think :)

Answer (score 0):

A few problems I can see with your code.

> ```
> input = int()`
> ```

`input` in the name of a function that gets an input string from the user. `int()` simply returns `0`. You are assigning the value `0` to a variable named `input`, making the input function no longer accessible.

> ```
> for i in range(0,input):
>   e = int(intput())
> ```

Because `input` is `0`, this is an empty range. The loop never runs. Which is good because it would have no idea what `intput` is.

Because the loop never runs, `e` is never defined, which is why you get the error you do.

Another style note: `arr1` is a `list` so using a name that suggests it's an array is misleading.

You likely wanted something like the following tweaked version of your code.

```
n = int(input())

vals = []
for _ in range(0, n):
    e = int(input())
    vals.append(e)

k = min(vals)

for i in range(0, n):
    arr1[i] = -= k
    
for i in range(0, n):
    print(arr1[i])
```

Gathering the input numbers could be simplified using a list comprehension.

```
vals = [int(input()) for _ in range(0, n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

When analyzing data sets, such as data for human heights or for human weights, a common step is to adjust the data. This adjustment can be done by normalizing to values between 0 and 1, or throwing away outliers.

For this program, adjust the values by dividing all values by the largest value. The input begins with an integer indicating the number of floating-point values that follow.

Output each floating-point value with two digits after the decimal point.

This is how I went about solving this problem.

```
# Get the number of floating points the user wants to use
user_num = int(input())

# Declare num_list to store floating points from the user
num_list = []

# Get floating point numbers from the user and add them to num_list 
for i in range(user_num):
    num_list.append(float(input()))

# Find the largest floating point 
max_num = max(num_list)

# Divide each floating point number in num_list by the max_num and print the result
for num in num_list:
    num_result = num / max_num
    print(f'{num_result:.2f}')
```

Answer (score -1):

This may be helpful for your lab:

```
user_int = []

while True:
  user_input = int(input())
  user_int.append(int(user_input))

  if len(user_int) > (int(user_int[0])):
    break

user_int.pop(0)

vals = min(user_int)

for user_vals in user_int:
  my_vals = user_vals - vals
  print(my_vals)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for contributing an answer but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the problem?

Comment: I can't help but feel like your approach to looping to gather the values from input is excessively "clever" and obfuscated vs. prompting for a number to input and then clearly looping that many times.